# is opencv::dnn module compatible with Ubuntu

Tags: opencv

I have compiled an application (YOLOv3) using opencv::dnn module on windwos. Now I want to compile the same application on Ubuntu. But I am unable to run it.
Have some worked on opencv::dnn in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes it is compatible. But you have to enable CUDA support when you first compile OpenCV.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining how to compile opencv with cuda support. Please let me know if you encounter any error.

Answer (score 0):

First and before everything, make sure you have CUDA and CuDNN installed.
Second, follow these steps to install opencv with CUDA support.

Let's install some dependencies:

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt upgrade -y --no-install-recommends
sudo apt install -y build-essential pkg-config cmake git wget curl unzip
sudo apt install -y libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt install -y ffmpeg
sudo apt install -y libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev libavresample-dev
sudo apt install -y libyaml-cpp-dev libgoogle-glog-dev libgflags-dev
```

Then install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

We will install opencv 4.2.0 in `/opt/` folder, so run `cd /opt/` 
Then run the following command to download OpenCV 4.2.0:

```
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/4.2.0.zip
```

After that, run the following command to download the contrib modules of OpenCV:

```
wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/archive/4.2.0.zip
```

Once you finish, unzip the downloaded files:

```
unzip opencv.zip
unzip opencv_contrib.zip
```

We are now ready to use cmake to configure our build. Take special care when running these commands:

```
cd opencv-4.2.0  
mkdir build  
cd build
```

Once you create the needed folder, run this command to start compiling opencv:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/opencv_contrib-4.2.0/modules /opt/opencv-4.2.0/ -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DBUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON -D WITH_CUDNN
```

`cmake` will take around 5 min to build all OpenCV and Cuda NVCC library. After this,  execute the following command:

```
make-j4
```

Once `make-j4` completes, run:

```
make install
```

If you get errors, run `sudo make install` instead.

Finally, run:

```
ldconfig
```

Or `sudo ldconfig` if you encounter permission denied.

**Credits:**  [Compile Opencv with Cuda from the source.](https://medium.com/@bnarasapur/compile-opencv-with-cuda-from-the-source-1b98e9108a59)

**Addtional resources:**
- [Accelerate OpenCV 4.2.0 – build with CUDA and python bindings](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-2-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/)
- [How to use OpenCV’s “dnn” module with NVIDIA GPUs, CUDA, and cuDNN](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/)

Comment: The source is wrong. You also need to add `-DWITH_CUDNN` and `-DOPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON` to enable the CUDA backend in the DNN module.

Comment: [This](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/) and [this](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-2-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings) are more reliable sources for building OpenCV with CUDA support.

Comment: @Yashas, thank you. I'll fix it.